# Выбор веб-сервера для wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-сервер, openserver, mamp

Нашел [Курс по WordPress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NNtOXgNPBM&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=2&t=0s) Как я понял - там используется сервер MAMP. Но я до этого использовал OpenServer. Хочу спросить какой сервер лучшее использовать, чтобы попасть в струю - т.е. какой веб сервер используется в it фирмах (Краснодара, windows 7 и выше) и для каких существуют видеоуроки?

Comment: Что там используется в IT-фирмах Краснодара, мне неведомо, но самые современные локальные серверы для Windows - это Laragon https://laragon.org/ и Flywheel Local Lightning https://getflywheel.com/layout/product-updates/local-lightning/

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется без разницы OpenServer или MAMP на локальном Вашем компьютере, я сам использую OpenServer. На реальном хостинге чаще всего вы будете выбирать только версию PHP, в настройки самого сервера лазить не придется, хотя для этого есть просто файл .htaccess, который можно кинуть в папку с сайтом, в случае если Вам понадобиться настроить кодировку или перенаправление. Ну а в общем для курса по WordPress это точно не имеет никакого значения.